# how to pass python package to spark job and invoke main file from package with arguments

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have my python code with a structure like,

```
Project1
--src
----util.py
----job1.py
----job2.py
--config
----config1.json
----config2.json
```

I want to run this job1 in spark but these I just cannot invoke job1.py because its dependent on other files like util.py and job2.py and config files and thus I need to pass complete package as an input to spark.

I tried running `spark-submit job1.py` but it fails with dependencies like job2.py and util.py because they are not available to executors.

Based on spark documentation, I see --files is an option to do this but it works by passing all filenames to spark-submit which looks difficult if number of files in codebase in future.

Another option I see is passing code zip file with --archive option but still it fails because not able to reference files in zip.

So Can anyone suggest any other way to run such codebase in spark?

Comment: Did you able submit this app to spark cluster ?

Answer (score 10):

Specific to your question, you need to use `--py-files` to include python files that should be made available on the PYTHONPATH.

I just ran into a similar problem where I want to run a modules main function from a module inside an egg file.

The wrapper code below can be used to run `main` for any module via spark-submit.  **For this to work you need to drop it into a python file using the package and module name as the filename**.  The filename is then used inside the wrapper to identify which module to run.  This makes for a more natural means of executing packaged modules without needing to add extra arguments (which can get messy).

Here's the script:

```
"""
Wrapper script to use when running Python packages via egg file through spark-submit.

Rename this script to the fully qualified package and module name you want to run.
The module should provide a ``main`` function.

Pass any additional arguments to the script.

Usage:

  spark-submit --py-files <LIST-OF-EGGS> <PACKAGE>.<MODULE>.py <MODULE_ARGS>
"""
import os
import importlib


def main():
    filename = os.path.basename(__file__)
    module = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    module = importlib.import_module(module)
    module.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You won't need to modify any of this code.  It's all dynamic and driven from the filename.

As an example, if you drop this into `mypackage.mymodule.py` and use spark-submit to run it, then the wrapper will import `mypackage.mymodule` and run `main()` on that module.  All command line arguments are left intact, and will be naturally picked up by the module being executed.

You will need to include any egg files and other supporting files in the command.  Here's an example:

```
spark-submit --py-files mypackage.egg mypackage.mymodule.py --module-arg1 value1
```

Answer (score 7):

There a few basic steps:

- Create a Python package.
- Either build `egg` file or create a simple `zip` archive.
- Add package as a dependency using `--py-files` / `pyFiles`.
- Create a thin `main.py` which invokes functions from the package and submit it to Spark cluster.

Comment: how to refer to a function from a zip? I understand that it has to be imported in the progra to be used later.

Answer (score 4):

A convenient solution in general **IMO** is using [**`setuptools`**](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/). It will come into handy when your project has too many dependent packages (Python file).

- First, put an empty `__init__` file on each directory which has the code file to be imported. This will help the package to be visible to the `import` statement.
- After installing `setuptools`, create a simple `set_up.py` file ([sample here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)). Remember to place it at the outermost directory which is your `src` folder.

  ```
  from setuptools import setup, find_packages
  setup(
      name = "name_of_lib",
      version = "0.0.1",
      author = "your name",
      packages = find_packages()
  )
  ```

The `find_packages` config will collect all your packages within that folder recursively.

- Run `python set_up.py bdist_egg`, and finally check out the `.egg` file in the `dist` folder.
- Submit your job using either `--py-files` or`addPyFile` of SparkContext.

And it **works like a charm**!

Comment: ```__init__.py``` to the importable directories was very important for this to work. I just added that empty file in every directory and subdirectory and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable: `/path-to-your-spark-directory/python`.
Also your path variable should have location of spark/bin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a bit more flexibility, i.e run files, modules or even a script specified on the command line, you can use something like the following launcher script:

`launcher.py`

```py
import runpy
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def split_passthrough_args():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    try:
        sep = args.index('--')
        return args[:sep], args[sep + 1:]
    except ValueError:
        return args, []


def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Launch a python module, file or script')
    source = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    source.add_argument('-m', type=str, help='Module to run', dest='module')
    source.add_argument('-f', type=str, help="File to run", dest='file')
    source.add_argument('-c', type=str, help='Script to run', dest='script')
    parser.add_argument('--', nargs='*', help='Arguments', dest="arg")
    self_args, child_args = split_passthrough_args()
    args = parser.parse_args(self_args)
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], *child_args]

    if args.file:
        runpy.run_path(args.file, {}, "__main__")
    elif args.module:
        runpy.run_module(f'{args.module}.__main__', {}, "__main__")
    else:
        runpy._run_code(args.script, {}, {}, "__main__")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It tries to emulate the Python interpreter's behavior, so when you have a package with the following module hierarchy

```
mypackage
  mymodule
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
```

where `__main__.py` contains the following:

```py
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(f"Hello {sys.argv[1]}!")
```

which you built and packaged as `mypackage.whl`; you can run it with

```
spark-submit --py-files mypackage.whl launcher.py -m mypackage.mymodule -- World
```

Supposing the package is preinstalled and available on /my/path/mypackage on the driver:

```
spark-submit launcher.py -f /my/path/mypackage/mymodule/__main__.py -- World
```

You could even submit a script:

```
spark-submit launcher.py -c "import sys; print(f'Hello {sys.argv[1]}')" -- World
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Question: would it be possible to have this launcher script packaged within the wheel/egg file itself and then to access it from within the wheel/package file. The reason I would prefer to have the launcher script within the package is because I'm not sure how a standalone script like this could be stored in a PyPI repository like Artifactory, but maybe there's a different way?

Comment: I don't thinks it can be packaged as Spark requires a top level py file as its positional argument AFAIK. However this script is general enough so it can be shipped with your Spark distribution if it is feasible for your use case. E.g if you build Spark as Docker image, you could add this file there.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue while working on PySpark.

Here is how you can solve this issue:
Assuming `src` is the python package, ZIP the complete src package into in a zip file let's say `code.zip` before that restructure `job1.py`.

```
Project1
--src
----util.py
----job1.py
----job2.py
---- __init__.py
--config
----config1.json
----config2.json
```

Since you want to run the `job1.py` and has dependencies from `job2.py` and `utils.py` let's structure `job1.py`.

```py
from . import job1 as j1
from . import util as ut


def compute(spark: SparkSession, job_args: T.List[str]) -> None:
    # core data processing logic
    .....
```

Now let's write a `driver.py` which calls this compute function.

```py
import argparse
import importlib
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Spark application to execute '
                                                 'other Spark apps.')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--module', action='store', dest='module',
        required=True,
        help='Name of the Spark module with a compute entry-point'
    )

    (args, job_args) = parser.parse_known_args()

    app_name = args.module.split('.')[-1]
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName(app_name) \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

    spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')

    job_module_name = args.module
    job_module = importlib.import_module(job_module_name)

    job_module.compute(spark, job_args)
```

Use following command to run the app:

```bash
   spark-submit --master yarn --py-files ./code.zip driver.py --module src.job1
```

So now you are all set to run your spark app.