# How do I call pyspark code with .whl file?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-packaging, python-wheel

I have used poetry to create a wheel file.
I am running following spark-submit command , but it is not working. I think I am missing something

```
spark-submit --py-files /path/to/wheel
```

Please note that I have referred to below as well, but did not get much details as I am new to Python.
[how to pass python package to spark job and invoke main file from package with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905546/how-to-pass-python-package-to-spark-job-and-invoke-main-file-from-package-with-a/52066867#)

Comment: You still need to add another parameter for which script to invoke with the main function

Comment: Yeah I added another parameter. It was 
Spark-submit --py-files wheelfile driver.py

This driver was calling the function inside wheelfile. But then this driver and wheel are in same location essentially. What is the use of wheel then? Because if I run the command with
spark-submit driver.py . Then also its the same  Right??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "location". Spark applications are distributed. The `--py-files` argument will serialize those files and distribute them into the cluster. Then the `driver.py` file tells which module from those files to execute. Sure, they need to all be on the `PYTHONPATH`, but that's not specific to Spark

Comment: Location refers to the same path (Mounted Path). What will the difference between these 2 approaches:
spark-submit driver.py 
******************************

spark-submit --py-files wheelfile driver.py

Comment: Assuming `driver.py` will import some module that is contained in the wheel/egg/zip that is uploaded, then the first option will be unable to find that code

Comment: Actually I have created wheel out of my main project itself. I am not sure if I am doing it right or not. I create a poetry package first , then wrote code inside package file for spark. Then did poetry build which created wheel file. Then running this command. 
and I have observed that even when I am passing this wheel file in --py-file , it is not taking the source code from wheel file. Instead it is taking it from package folder .

Comment: I assume youre using `local` as your spark master? Not a cluster/remote machine?

Comment: Yes. For testing I am using it on Local. So basically in distributed mode , It will refer to the wheel file only to read the transformation in the source code , instead of reading the code from package. Is it correct?

Comment: Does poetry only build the wheel, or does it also fully install it into the python environment? That might be what youre seeing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223524/discussion-between-sachit-murarka-and-onecricketeer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wheel file can be executed as a part of below spark-submit command

spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --py-files /path/to/wheel main_file.py

Comment: I don't think this is correct. From the documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.htm) about `spark.submit.pyFiles`:  `Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps`. Since basically they do the same, I don't  expect It to handle wheel files.

Comment: Wheel files works fine. I have tried it and tested it, it is working fine.

Comment: Then they really should update the documentation :)

Comment: @SachitMurarka how did you test it exactly? I can't make it work.

Comment: @SachitMurarka is `main_file.py` something inside your `.whl` file or a separate python file?

Comment: Nevermind I see it is a separate file. I think @CesareIurlaro is technically correct - whl files are zipimport compatible but using `--py-files` will not install the wheel. If your wheel is just a zip archive with no install required it will work, but if your wheel requires / expects to be installed then it won't work for example if there are c/c++ dependencies in the wheel. See https://databricks.com/blog/2020/12/22/how-to-manage-python-dependencies-in-pyspark.html